# Output multiple lines of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I used

```
while (cond) { ...
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k); ... }
```

I want

```
while (cond) { ...
    arr.append("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k); ... }
printf("%s", arr);
```

What's the best practice to do similar in C?

Comment: Why not stick with the first code?

Comment: @ForceBru: Faster.

Comment: use [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to store into a buffer and finally print the buffer at once.,

Comment: @Rainning - How can you know it's faster? You haven't measured both yet. The first approach may write to stdout at every iteration, but the second would involve memory allocation (and maybe even re-allocation). I wouldn't risk guessing which is faster.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The ideal case in my imagination: Each iteration the input string has a different length `n`, then I allocate exactly enough space for a `char *` to catch it, then store it in `char * []`, then next iteration. Can `snprintf()` you mentioned do the same?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Good point. I will try it after this would be solved. In my current case the input has > 1000 strings, so I made this conclusion.

Comment: First code involves `printf()` only. Suggested solutions involve `snprintf()`, `malloc()` or `realloc()`, sometimes a `printf()` as well, and a final `printf()`. I bet the first code is faster.

Comment: @mouviciel: You're correct, I checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to store the combined output and print that at the end, or at intermediary steps if needed:

```
char arr[32768];
size_t size = sizeof(arr), pos = 0;
while (cond) { ...
    size_t len = snprintf(arr + pos, size - pos, "%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
    if (pos + len >= size) {
        printf("%.*s", (int)pos, arr);
        pos = 0;
        len = snprintf(arr + pos, size - pos, "%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
    }
    pos += len;
    ...
}
printf("%.*s", (int)pos, arr);
```

Note however that the above code emulates the very behavior of `printf` with a larger buffer and might still be slower than calling `printf` directly. You can control the buffer size for the stream using `setvbuf()`:

```
setvbuf(stdout, 32768, _IOFBF);
```

You can try larger buffer sizes and benchmark your code to assess any impact on performance.

Comment: Performance note: This is slower than `printf` on each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (cond) { ...
    int i = printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k); 
    char *newstring = malloc(i + 1);
    /* some error checks */ 
    snprintf(newstring, i+1, "%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
    arr.append(newstring); ... }
```

Comment: `arr.append` in C? How?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Wait - you will see

Comment: It's not about me being happy, it's about writing meaningful code. Just because it can be done, does not mean it should be done. I guess this creates more confusion, which is unnecessary and can easily be avoided.